# Database for Junit Testing

Tags: java, junit

I am coding crud APIs for my application built on Hibernate/SQL. I am using mysql for both testing and live environment.

For testing, I have a database, user and privileges. So every time to test, I have to follow these steps:

1. Drop all tables from database.
2. Run "mvn clean install", and hibernate looks for the table in db and creates them if not existing.

I want my testing such that it doesn't collect garbage in my mysql db and I don't have to drop tables each and every time. Is there some in-memory rdbms which can be used for this purpose, and how can I choose between this and mysql depending on run environment is for testing or live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer using H2, dbUnit, and spring-test. Hsqldb and Derby are other in-memory databases that are reasonable choices. Tests in spring use their own separate context with their own datasource, the test context configuration supersedes the normal application context values. That way there is no extra effort required to switch between databases, the tests can be setup to use H2 while the application uses mysql.

Be aware that mysql is permissive about the sql it accepts, other databases tend to be more strict. If you use native sql that may be an obstacle to using an in-memory database.

I think it pays off to have tests exercising your data layer, especially when using Hibernate, which is complicated enough that I want to confirm it's really doing what I think it should be doing.

Comment: I have those DAO tests sometimes too, but usually they are unit tests - just testing the database access - and I let those cascade through to a "real" database rather than an in memory one.  That way they test the table metadata is correct as well, not just the code accessing them.  But with tests of code in other layers that access the DAOs, that's when I usually stub or mock them out rather than let them fall through.

Comment: @Jim: thanks, i edited so i don't mischaracterize your views

Answer (score 1):

HSQLDB and H2 I think are pretty common choices.

Personally I don't go down this route anymore - I just stub out DAOs with test doubles when running unit tests so that they write to or read from lists in memory, or provide mocks for them.  No complex technology.  It does mean that the actual persistence to DB is not being tested - if I feel I need that, I generally will write separate unit tests for the DAOs themselves to specifically connect to physical DB, and clean up whatever I need to in the teardown of those tests.